# android Google map API v2 doesn't display street names

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm displaying a map using google maps API v2 but it doesn't show any street names. It shows the satellite image but no text. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmaps);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater()));
    map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    mMyLocation = map.getMyLocation();
    setMarkerOnLocation();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works as designed. You are setting the map in Satellite mode and according to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#map_types

**Satellite**

Satellite photograph data. Road and feature labels are **not visible**.

**Hybrid**

Satellite photograph data with road maps added. Road and feature labels are also visible.

So you'll need to use the following if you want the labels to show:

```
GoogleMap map;
...
// Sets the map type to be "hybrid"
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just given current location and didnt given any latitude and longitude points

For example:

```
  LatLng one = new LatLng(13.549881,77.711792);//

  Marker myMarkerOne = gm.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(one)
        .title("Name of location")
        .snippet("Name of street")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

and if you want to get dynamically means use json map parsing which is given [here](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-with-photos-at-any-location-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/).

Comment: I didn't mean a specific location. I meant when the map is loaded, it doesn't show any street names, highways, buildings, etc. when zooming in & out. Isn't that delivered automatically with the api?

Comment: whether map looks blank? will u please add screenshot? u have added satellite,so it will load street names.